# Facing recursive property values, when debugging one to many relationship program using Entity Framework 6 program

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have two model classes with a one-to-many relationship:

```
public class Employee
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public String EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public int DeptId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DeptId")]
    public  Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Department
{      
    public Department()
    {
        Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public  ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code I'm trying to insert records into the `Departments` and `Employees` tables:

```
using (var cxt = new CompanyContext())
{
    Department d = new Department() { DepartmentId = 28, Name = "Science" };
    cxt.Departments.Add(d);

    Department dn = new Department() { DepartmentId = 27, Name = "Philately" };
    cxt.Departments.Add(dn);

    Employee e = new Employee() { EmployeeId = 207, EmployeeName = "Sheez", Department = d };                   
    Employee en = new Employee() { EmployeeId = 208, EmployeeName = "Adn" };
    en.Department = d;    

    cxt.Employees.Add(e);
    cxt.Employees.Add(en);                    

    cxt.SaveChanges();    

    Employee er = cxt.Employees.SingleOrDefault(o => o.EmployeeId == 207); // retrieving Employee for testing,here I get the Department details also. I wonder how could EF retreive the Department entity without me specifying the Include method.               
}
```

Context class

```
public class CompanyContext:DbContext
{
        public CompanyContext()
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }

        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}
```

**Issue 1**

When I debug and view either the `Departments` or the `Employees` property, I see recursive property values like `Departments` having `Employees` property which again have `Departments` property and so on.

[image: Snapshot of Debugging mode]

This seems very weird to me. I haven't seen such a thing anytime till now. I'm I going wrong in my code or is this the common thing happens in debugging?

**Issue 2**

According to most stuff on Eager loading and lazy loading, my understanding is

1. If I mark navigation properties virtual then related entities are not loaded until they are first used in the code. But will they be visible in entity objects in debug mode? Since I was able to view the `Employees` in the debug mode in `Departments`.
2. If I don't mark them virtual then Eager loading will happen. In my case EF retrieved the related entity i.e `Department` though I haven't specified the `Include` method. I'm unable to make out how is it loading related entity automatically.
   Since I have seen a project in which lazy loading is disabled, and the related entities properties in debug mode, goes null except the foreign key pointing to the record, and loads the related entities using the `Include`, wherever required.

Clarification regarding my queries would be greatly helpful and regarded as a favour. Thank you.

Comment: That is what you have defined. `Employee` has a property `Department`, which again loops back to a `ICollection<Employee>` via another property. Are you facing any problems because of it?

Comment: Untill now I have no issues with this circular definition but I was stuck as to why this is happening. I followed [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) in which there is Convention 3 which I have used here.

Comment: Such bidirectional associations are perfectly normal in an EF class model. It's no recursion. It's a circular reference. There are plenty .Net classes having the same types of associations.

Answer (score 0):

You have created the recursion yourself. Entity Framework is exactly doing what you tell it.

Its the same as:

```
public class Foo
{
     public Bar Bar
     {
         get
         {
             //EF would load this from cache, if alrady exists
             return new Bar();
         }
     } 
}
public class Bar
{
     public Foo Foo
     {
         get
         {
             //EF would load this from cache, if alrady exists
             return new Foo();
         }
     } 
}
```

I think important to note is, that a Getter is only executed, if it is accessed. This could be happen through code (`foo.Bar`) or through debugging (expand `Bar` of `Foo`). (Also explains 2.1)

The Entity Framework should also cache the result, if once obtained. That said, I don't think it will become a problem. (Also explains 2.2; Its the same object reference.)

If you don't want the recursion, remove one property, which is pointing to another.

Comment: Thank you for making me clear. But I think expanding the node during debugging doesn't make it accessible. It happens only through code.

Comment: Not sure about the details how exactly it works. Maybe via reflection. The important thing is, it only executing the getter if you want to show the information. @RaidaAdn

Answer (score 0):

**Note 1**
There should be navigation property at any one side of relationship, if present at both sides leads to circular references.

**Note 2**
In my code where I'm trying to insert record into `Employee` and `Departments` tables, I have accessed the Navigation properties.

```
cxt.Departments.Add(d);
```

As Christian Gollhardt suggested, EF have stored the related entities in Cache and it was loading it automatically creating a magic for me. I expected that EF might be creating a separate memory allocation for retrieving the Employee than the insert operation.

Hence I separate the retrieving of `Employee` to an another function then I can observe the eager loading phenomena of making `Department` property null and can be loaded by using the `Include` method.